# Averaging weekly figures into quarterly figures

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula that averages values in column D only if they're in Q1, Q2, etc. This list will go beyond 2021, so the formula can't average just any values in jan, feb, and march, for Q1 (for example). Essentially is has to be year specific as well.

To specify, I was wanting to make some sort of index match formula that would find, and average, the values.

I've tried many formulas but can't figure it out.

[image: excel_file_i'm_stuck_on.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where are the values averaged? In the total row at the bottom? If so, you're looking to average only the values in column D where column C's value falls within Q1 / Q2?

Comment: Not quite understanding what conditions you need to help you achieve the result.

Comment: The weeks can average into months, anywhere really. They end up in a graph that pulls monthly data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to place these averages elsewhere, then here's one solution. You probably already have these formulas, but placing here anyway....

Column C: **Quarter formula**

```
    =ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2)/3,0)
```

Column D: **Year formula**

```
    =YEAR(A2)
```

Then in your aggregation area, you could use this formula.

Cell I2 formula for **Averaging by Quarter and Year**:

```
    =IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($B:$B,$D:$D,$H2,$C:$C,I$1),0)
```

This AVERAGEIFS formula can be dragged across and down, then you're done.

[image]